# Select default value if column has 0 value in SQL Server

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008

If the column has 0 value, I need to select like 'xyz' with other select column value

For example,

```
 id    col1   col2
 1       0     abc
 2       2     xyz
```

I need to select all column in this table but `col1` if has 0 then need to show 'xyz'.

Comment: pargan, whats the date type of col1, integer or varchar?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
select id,
       case when col1 = '0' then 'xyz' else convert(varchar, col1) end as col1,
       col2
from table
```

You must use a CASE :)

Comment: You are supposing col1 to be varchar in case condition and also doing type cast to varchar in else portion. why?

Comment: If the field is non-nullable you can also use this formula
ISNULL(NULLIF(col1,0),'xyz')

Answer (score 1):

```
Select id, Case when col1 = 0 then 'xyz' else cast(col1  as varchar(10)) end as col1, col2 from table
```

Comment: Don't col1 must be converted to varchar?

Comment: if col1 is varchar then no need to convert, else conversion is required.

Comment: what's the reason for down voting.

Answer (score 1):

```
select id,
       case 
         when col1 = 0 then 'xyz' 
         else cast(col1 as varchar(50))
       end as result_column,
       col2
from table
```

Comment: You are supposing col1 to be varchar in case condition and also doing type cast to varchar in else portion. why?

Comment: 'xyz' is varchar, so col1 must be varchar or converted to it.

Comment: because 'xyz' is varchar and if you try to join int with varchar on the same column it will fail. Also, everything can be cast to a varchar, so whats the problem?

Comment: In that way condition should be col1 = 0 instead of col1='0'.

Comment: no it shouldt. Col1 is integer (lets assume that), but the result needs to be casted to varchar because it will be merged with string 'xyz'

Comment: I am asking if col1 is integer then why you are comparing the col1 value with '0' as text comparison in when condition.

Comment: oh ok, got ya. I've updated my answer. Again, I'm considering col1 as integer and casting the result as varchar because it may be merged with 'xyz'

Comment: In this case, my solution is also fine. So it should not get -1.